# Axios is sending array instead of json object in post request

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to send a post request using axios from Vuejs front-end to Laravel in backend.

```
const data = {
            file: {id}
        }

        axios.post('api/documents/remove', data).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        }).catch(err => { console.log(err.response.data); })
```

In laravel, I am printing the request like this,

```
 public function removeFile(Request $request)
 { 
    dd($request);
 }
```

This is my output.

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#51
  #json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#43
  #parameters: array:8 [
  "file" => array:1 [
    "id" => 61
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. You can access the data from of the $request object Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: you should look how JavaScript object react with php

Comment: AJAX request expects (json) string. Just return response `return response()->json($request->all(), 200);`.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's "[arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)" aren't really arrays, they're *ordered maps*. That's what your output is showing, that the request contains paramters, which is an ordered map, and the `file` parameter is an ordered map with `id => 61` in it. In JavaScript that would be an object (or `Map`, sometimes); in many other languages it would be some kind of map or dictionary. PHP calls them arrays.

Either way, if you access the `file` parameter (I don't "do" Laravel so I don't know how you do that), you can get the `id` from it like this: `$file[`id`]`. Looking at the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value), it looks like that would be:

```
$file = $request->input('file');
$id = $file['id'];
```

Comment: earlier I was accessing the item inside file array like `$request->file->id`

Now it is showing error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: @Abhimanu - That isn't how you get an entry's value from a PHP associative array, that's how you get an object property's value. They're distinct things. I haven't used Laravel (much or recently) so I don't know about the `$request->file` part of that, but assuming it's valid (the docs suggest it would be `$request->input('file')` but maybe the other is a shorthand), you'd want `$request->file['id']`. Again, though, to be clear: This is a PHP thing, how "property bags" are handled in PHP, not an Axios thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of $request as

```php
$file = $request->input('file');
$file['id'];

//Or

$fileId = $request->input('file.id');
```

Comment: I want to access it like `$request->file->id` now it is showing error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: Obviously it will throw an error `$request->file or $request->input('file')` is an array can't access it elements with object notation. Have shown the possible ways in the answer to access `id`

Answer (score 0):

Request `$request` is delivering array not object instance, so, you can access only like the followings:

```
$request->input('file')['id']
```

Or

```
$request->file['id']
```

Or

```
$request->input('file.id')
```

Or, only file field

```
$request-all()[0]['file']['id']
```